# How to backup/restore a Firebird database?

Tags: backup, firebird, restore

I am really confused here about Firebird v2.5 backup/restore process. What should I use to backup/restore a local Firebird database:
**fbsvcmgr.exe**, **gbak.exe**, **isql.exe** or **nbackup.exe**

Are these all options or I am wrong about something!

What is the practical way to do it for a C++ application?

How should I know if a database already exists the first time, so I can decide whether to restore it or not.

Comment: http://www.ibpp.org/reference/service?s[]=backup#service_methods_backuprestore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two primary ways to create backups in Firebird:

- *gbak*, which creates a logical backup of the database (object 'descriptions' (e.g. table structure, views, etc) and data)
- *nbackup* (also known as nbak), which creates a physical backup of the database (physical data pages changed since the previous nbackup)

In most cases, I'd suggest to use *gbak*, because it is simpler and also allows you to move backups between platforms and Firebird versions, while *nbackup* is only really suitable for the same platform and Firebird version (but has the advantage of allowing incremental backups).

ISQL is an interactive query CLI, and cannot be used to create backups. *Fbsvcmgr* is the "Firebird Service Manager" tool, which can be used to invoke service operations on a (remote) Firebird server. This includes backup and restore operations through *gbak* and *nbackup*. *Fbsvcmgr* is pretty low-level and hard to use (see `fbsvcmgr -?` for options).

For *gbak*, you'd normally invoke the services through the *gbak* executable (option `-se[rvice] <service>`), see also [Remote Backups & Restores](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html#gbak-recipies-remote) in the *gbak* documentation. For *nbackup* you either can use the *nbackup* tool locally, or you need to use the *fbsvcmgr* (or another tool that supports service operations) to invoke the same functionality remotely (`action_nbak` and `action_nrest`), see also [Backups on remote machines (Firebird 2.5+)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html#nbackup-backups-remote) in the *nbackup* documentation.

For detailed description on *gbak*, see [gbak - Firebird Backup & Restore Utility](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gbak/firebird-gbak.html). For *nbackup*, see [Firebird's nbackup tool](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/nbackup/firebird-nbackup.html).

With a *gbak* backup, you'd normally restore the database using 'create' (option `-c[reate]`) or 'recreate' (`-r[ecreate]` **without** `o[verwrite]` option), which will fail if the database file already exists. See also the *gbak* manual linked above for more information.

I won't really answer your question about how to do it from a C++ application, because I don't program C++, and your question is already too broad as it is. But know that it is possible to invoke Firebird service operations, including backup and restore using both *gbak* and *nbackup*, from C++ code (that is essentially what Firebird tools itself do). If you want to know more about that, I'd suggest you ask on the [firebird-support Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support).

Answer (score 13):

I usually use gbak (don't know about the others).

**Backup**

gbak -b -v -user SYSDBA -password "masterkey" D:\database.FDB E:\database.fbk

**Restore**

gbak -c -user SYSDBA -password masterkey E:\database.fbk E:\database_restore.fdb

If file exists for restore you could do it with gbak restore flags
-c = create new file
-r = replace file

Here is good page for FB backup/restore: http://www.destructor.de/firebird/gbak.htm

Comment: The `-r` option is recreate and it will behave the same as `-c`, unless you use `-r o` (`-recreate overwrite`). The replace option is `-rep`. That is assuming a recent Firebird version.